# Send build artifacts in an email via TeamCity

Tags: email, teamcity, devops

Is there any way of sending TeamCity build artifacts which include execution report (*.html) via email when the build is successfully executed?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it's not possible to send any attachments - you can vote for this issue [TW-7318](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-7318)

However you can list/link to the build artifacts but this is also not fully recommended. See the [TeamCity Docs](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD18/Customizing+Notifications#CustomizingNotifications-Listingbuildartifacts)

Comment: Thank-you for your reference. For now, I've added notification filters to serve the purpose which has the link embedded to view artifacts generated.